# How do I check for browser errors in Safari on iOS if I don't have a Mac to connect it to?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I have a javascript slideshow that works on everything except iOS - both Safari and Chrome. I want to see if it's throwing any helpful error messages, but to view Safari error messages, I need to connect the device to a Mac. (I've checked to make sure that Javascript is turned on, of course.)

**Are there any other ways to read browser errors in iOS?** I've been searching around, but haven't found anything. I'm not familiar with the Apple ecosystem though, so it's quite likely that I'm missing something. (I'm a Windows & Android guy.)

If anyone wants to take a look, the site is www.northerntool.com. It's the big slideshow at the top. (The relevant javascript starts at line 1863 in the source code.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use browserstack but if you don't have it, please see the screenshot: https://ibb.co/J7H4NPQ

Comment: (in global.js ) Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #slidebox [class*="slide"

Comment: Thanks so much. My issue was a TYPO! Argh.

Answer (score 0):

From user CS54:

> (in global.js ) Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #slidebox [class*="slide" –

Thanks!